# Getting errors on Hello-Wordpress Sample

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Following the steps from https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/hello-wordpress

all works until I get to "gcloud compute instances list" I get these errors:

`[ec2-user@ip-10-00-00-000~]$ gcloud compute instances list
NAME ZONE MACHINE_TYPE INTERNAL_IP EXTERNAL_IP STATUS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 175, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 171, in main
    _cli.Execute()
  File "/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 385, in Execute
    post_run_hooks=self.__post_run_hooks, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/frontend.py", line 274, in _Execute
    pre_run_hooks=pre_run_hooks, post_run_hooks=post_run_hooks)
  File "/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 930, in Run
    output_formatter(result)
  File "/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 916, in OutputFormatter
    command_instance.Display(args, obj)
  File "/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/compute/lib/base_classes.py", line 304, in Display
    PrintTable(resources, self._resource_spec.table_cols)
  File "/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/compute/lib/base_classes.py", line 46, in PrintTable
    for resource in resources:
  File "/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/compute/lib/base_classes.py", line 289, in Run
    for item in items:
  File "/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/compute/lib/lister.py", line 29, in ProcessResults
    yield field_selector.Apply(resource)
  File "/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/compute/lib/property_selector.py", line 355, in Apply
    res = _DictToOrderedDict(obj)
  File "/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/compute/lib/property_selector.py", line 177, in _DictToOrderedDict
    new_obj = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(obj.items()))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OrderedDict'`

Since that works on my windows box I ignore and move to the next step and get these errors:

```
    [ec2-user@ip-10-00-00-000~]$ gcloud preview container pods create wordpress --cluster-name
    hello-world  --image=tutum/wordpress --port=80
    Usage: gcloud preview container pods create [optional flags]

    Create a pod running in a cluster.

    optional flags:
      --cluster-name CLUSTER_NAME, -n CLUSTER_NAME
                             The name of this cluster.
      --config-file CONFIG_FILE
                             Path to the pod config
      --format FORMAT        Format for printed output.
      --help                 Display detailed help.
      --image IMAGE          The Docker image to use
      --name NAME            The name of the pod
      --port PORT            A port to expose
      --project PROJECT_ID   Google Cloud Platform project ID to use for this
                             invocation.
      --purge-config-cache   Clear cached config data for the cluster. If set, will
                             call 'container clusters describe' directly to get
                             cluster data before executing kubernetes client
                             command.
      --quiet, -q            Disable all interactive prompts.
      --zone ZONE, -z ZONE   The compute zone (e.g. us-central1-a) for the cluster
      -h                     Print a summary help and exit.

    ERROR: (gcloud.preview.container.pods.create) unrecognized arguments: wordpress
```

tried reordering the parameters but still get the same error above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
gcloud preview container pods create --name wordpress --cluster-name hello-world --image=tutum/wordpress --port=80
```

The name of the pod is now specified as an argument as shown in the usage output:

"--name NAME The name of the pod"

Comment: Thanks, tried it but with these python errors I'm not sure of that worked:
`gcloud preview container pods create --name wordpress --cluster-name hello-world --image=tutum/wordpress --port=80
Traceback (most recent call last):...
  File "/home/ec2-user/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/container/lib/util.py", line 286, in WhichKubectl
    return subprocess.check_output(['which', 'kubectl'])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'`

Comment: calling `gcloud preview container pods describe wordpress` return similar errors

Comment: switched to ubuntu and python errors are gone, suggestion worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the list instances output it looks like your cloud-sdk installation may be broken. Try reinstalling the cloud sdk following instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/

Comment: Thanks, did that several times. could not get it to work. must be an amazon linux thing, switched to ubuntu and all works fine

Comment: When you installed the cloud sdk did you select the option to add it to your path?

Comment: Also, can you paste the output of python --version to show what version of python is installed on your EC2 VM?

Comment: it adds itself to the path just need to restart the shell. on the non working server the python version is Python 2.6.9 on the working ubuntu it's 2.7.6. I'll try to update and post results